# golang Compare time size

Tags: go

I want to make a comparison between the current time and the database data. My code is:

```
var PayBlockedLog[] model.PayBlockedLog
    global.DB.Where("status = ?",0).Find(&PayBlockedLog)
    for i := 0; i <len(PayBlockedLog); i++ {
        if time.Now().Unix() < PayBlockedLog[i].UnsealTime{

        }
    }
```

It seems that I should have PayBlockedLog[i].UnsealTime convert to int64.

After trying, there was no effect

Comment: Instead of fetching potentially a great many rows and then filtering them, could you do the comparison in the query? What database and library are you using? What is your schema?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than fetching and then filtering, do the filter in the query. This will save time and memory, as well as avoid time zone issues.

I don't know what database you're using, nor the column type of `UnsealTime`. If it's a `timestamp` or `datetime` (which it should be) check it against `current_timestamp`.

```
global
  .DB
  .Where("status = ? and current_timestamp < UnsealTime", 0)
  .Find(&PayBlockedLog)
```

If it's seconds since the Unix epoch, consider converting it to a normal `timestamp` column so date/time functions can be used. There are several ways to accomplish this while keeping the old column for compatibility.

Otherwise, you can convert the current time to epoch seconds. How you do this depends on the database. Here it is in Postgres.

```
global
  .DB
  .Where("status = ? and extract(epoch from current_timestamp) < UnsealTime", 0)
  .Find(&PayBlockedLog)
```